# Installing bathroom in basement

Tags: plumbing, bathroom

starting plans for a raised bathroom in my basement . I have ben looking on Google. YouTube etc. To figure out how to plumb the bathroom. Since I will not be breaking out concrete. How would I attach the new drain for shower sink and toilet to this existing cast iron line . Thanks [image]

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. Would you add information on what this picture shows? And, big props for [taking our tour](//diy.stackexchange.com/tour) before your first post; few people do...

Comment: I think adding the plumbing vent would be the most difficult part of this job, but I'll let others help that know more than me about this stuff. I feel like you'd need to remove concrete depending on how much you're raising the floor and how far away the toilet and shower is.

Comment: how much can you raise the floor of the shower by?

Comment: why not breaking concrete?

Answer (score 1):

Check out Saniflo up flush toilets; they're great for basements above/below grade. You can have a sink/shower/toilet that all drains to a pump/macerator unit either behind the toilet or in the vanity cabinet. Outlet pipes are usually 3/4" or 1" PVC that can be pumped up as high as 20 ft in order to reach most of your smaller drain lines, which are usually easier to tie into from the PVC pipe. No need to raise the bathroom.